# Bloodshed Error 1 in C program (newbie, first C program)

Tags: c

So i just started learning C using bloodshed as my compiler and stuff....
i am using book "C for dummies".
So this is what i did->

File>New>Source File

Then wrote this code->

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
printf("Goodbye, cruel world!\n"); 
return(0); 
}
```

Then went to Execute>Compile and Run.
But it says me in compiler as->

```
" C:\Users\Jaskaran\Documents\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Project1.exe] Error 1 "
```

Please help. This is basically my first C program.

My makefile.win content->

```
# Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

CPP  = g++.exe
CC   = gcc.exe
WINDRES = windres.exe
RES  = 
OBJ  = main.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = main.o $(RES)
LIBS =  -L"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/lib"  
INCS =  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include" 
CXXINCS =  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include" 
BIN  = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS)  
CFLAGS = $(INCS)  
RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before Project1.exe all-after


clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o "Project1.exe" $(LIBS)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c main.c -o main.o $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Basically, http://www.c-for-dummies.com/cfordummies/sourcecode/learn/goodbye.c. Does your compiler say *anything* more than "Error 1"?

Comment: Haven't used windows for years but I recall that in visual studio you needed to create a project as the first step before adding the SRC code. Perhaps it's the same thing here...

Comment: " C:\Users\Jaskaran\Documents\Makefile.win [Build Error][Project1.exe] Error 1 " -> thats all it says. I also tried New Project>C>Console application (thats what i need to select, right?)>then wrote the same code in it and compiled and same error.

Comment: Console is the correct target. It uses mingw as the compiler, Check in the settings that it is installed and that the path is correct

Comment: Am I going to have be that guy? One question, is this the same Bloodshed Dev++ that had its last update Feb 2005? Anyway that error comes from the make process when something executed as part of the process terminated with a non-zero status. Post contents of Makefile.win? Try running it in steps? Use a newer IDE? If you want to continue in similar env I have heard OK things about this http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: This is bloodshed 4.9.9 (my friend told me to use it an so... lol), should I use another? please recommend me one. And I added makefile.win contents on first post

Comment: `Bloodshed DevC++ 4.9.9` is very buggy. Do not ever use that. Instead use `Orwell DevC++ 5.5.1`.

Comment: There is usually more useful stuff after "Error 1" ... Like CXXXX <text>

Comment: There is nothing after error 1.  @haccks can i use netbeans with C/C++ plugin if thats ok?

Comment: I am using Orwell and no problem with that. download it from [here](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.in/).

Comment: ok, do i need to install mingw separately?

Comment: No. that's included in the package. see carefully, there are different packages. Download first for 32 bit or second one for 62 bit. Or you may like to use `Code:Block`. Its a good IDE.

Comment: thanks, its a fine compiler :D

Answer (score 2):

Use regular double-quotes like this: `"`

Comment: Check the code the OP posted... You would be surprised how often beginners copy wrong quotes from various web pages...

Comment: aactually... i directly copied this code from ebook, thats why those quotes... but otherwise i used normal "" ones in code and result was still same.

Comment: Never do that. Always copy the code you're trying to compile (see http://sscce.org/ for more guidance).

Comment: ok, from now on i will do. Actually, i wrote this code (not copied) in bloodshed but still got that error.